# Simple regex url-related matching help

Tags: regex, match, alphanumeric

Take the following URI:

```
http:\/\/.*\.google\.com/search/results\.php*
```

I am simply trying to match all single forward slashes ( / ) between two alphanumeric characters in a given URI. In the case above, the two just before search and results. Could you point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

The intention is to do search and replace using Notepad++.

Comment: Can you tell us what programming language you are using and what your code does with/as a result of this "match". The question isn't quite clear enough to me.

Comment: What about `http://example.com//index.html`? Do you really want to ignore that double-slash?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're doing there, as your “URI” is seemingly already a regex.

But to match a slash (`/`) embedded between alphanumeric characters, you can use:

```
/(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]/)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

A positive lookbehind and lookahead make sure that the slash is indeed between two alphanumeric characters.

Test in Windows PowerShell:

```
PS Home:\> $uri='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259778/simple-regex-url-related-matching-help'
PS Home:\> [regex]::matches($uri, '(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])/(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])') | ft -auto

Groups   Success   Captures   Index   Length   Value
------   -------   --------   -----   ------   -----
{/}         True   {/}           24        1   /
{/}         True   {/}           34        1   /
{/}         True   {/}           42        1   /
```

**ETA:** If I understood you correctly you want to replace slashes embedded between two alphanumeric characters by `\/` to escape them, right?

Then replacing the following

```
([a-zA-Z-0-9])/([a-zA-Z-0-9])
```

by

```
\1\\/\2
```

should work. This doesn't capture the slash only (as above method; due to limitations of Notepad++) therefore we have to reinsert the surrounding characters as well.

However, you probably want to search for *unescaped* slashes anyway. So replacing

```
([^\\])/
```

by

```
\1\\/
```

would make more sense, I think. This searches for a slash that is not preceded by a backslash.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I wanted to match it using regex. I have 100s of normal links that I'm trying to convert to regex in bulk. Using some pseudo methods I was able to format most of the links except for the slashes after the domain.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Perhaps it's a limitation of Notepad++ or I am simply forgetting how to setup the command, but n++ is not letting me search the document using your answer. Certainly looks like what I need though.

Comment: @user: Ah, SciTE, the underlying editor engine of Notepad++ has pretty crappy regex support. It's not very nice but somehow they never saw the need of fixing it. I'm adding something that might work; just a moment.

Comment: Better put the look-behind after the `/`: `/(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]/)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])`

Comment: @Gumbo: Just out of curiosity: What does that accomplish? Just that the RE engine doesn't try looking for a `/` after every alphanumeric char? (I don't know enough about how they work internally, hence the question.) Anyway, it won't work with lookaround anyway since Notepad++ is *coughs* a little braindead regarding regexes.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: When putting the look-behind in front of the `/`, the look-behind would be applied for each character; after the `/` it would only be tested if a `/` was already found.

Comment: I figured it might be an issue with Notepad++, hehe. Is there an alternative editor you would recommend that is a bit more current? I found N++ to be extremely powerful but it did feel a bit outdated at times.

Comment: @user: Not that I know of. I rarely need regular expressions in my editor anyway. Far introduced support for it sometime in Far 2, but I haven't tried it yet (and I don't know what features are there or what RE flavor it is).

Comment: +1 as far as I'm concerned. It answers the question, and it provides alternatives to the actual need (s&r with notepad++).

Answer (score 1):

http://.*.google.com/search/results.php*

Comment: Funny (duh).

Yes, that's what I was trying to accomplish, but without having to do it manually one by one for 100s of links.